# how to insert PHPSESSID into db with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] in db with pdo, but i am having issue, can somebody help out?

here is the db table design : db table name: `unregistered_customer_orders`

```
session_id (int)
sel_article_id (varchar, 32)
sel_article_qty(smallint)
sel_article_color(varchar)
sel_article_size(varchar)
order_date(datetime)
```

HERE IS THE CODE

```
session_start();
try {
include_once'../includes/connect.inc.php'; 
$q ="INSERT INTO unregistered_customer_orders SET 
session_id = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] ,
sel_article_id = :sel_article_id,
sel_article_qty =:sel_article_qty,
sel_article_color = :sel_article_color,
sel_article_size = :sel_article_size,
order_date = NOW()";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($q);
$stm->bindValue(':sel_article_id', $sel_article_id);
$stm->bindValue(':sel_article_qty', $sel_article_qty);
$stm->bindValue(':sel_article_color', $sel_article_color);
$stm->bindValue(':sel_article_size', $sel_article_size);
$stm->execute();

  if ($stm) {
    echo "Insert";
    exit();
  }
  else{
    echo "Insert failed";
    exit();
    }  
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "sth got wrong with the insert".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You are using prepared statements incorrectly. This `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` should be bound as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a serious SQL injection problem!

You inject unescaped SQL code into the query - or at least are trying to do so, from the cookie.

The cookie variable should go into the `bindValue` part just like everything else. Create a new variable name that goes into the prepared statement part, and bind the cookie value to it.

Note that PHP can be configured to use a different name for the session cookie! You don't have to access the $_COOKIE variable after you started the session, you can simply call the `session_id()` function to get the currently used session id.

Before using `session_start()`, the configured cookie name can be read by calling `session_name()`. Don't hardcode the cookie name into your code - it will create hard to debug errors when a new server has a different configuration.

Comment: thanks...for the answer.really appreciate..God..i forgot i could just use the session_id...into a variable and bind